# How to set value property of NumericUpDown from a string value?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to get values from a selected row of `DataGridView` and assign them into a few different
controls on a Form when a control's name match a column's name (there is `TextBox`, `ComboBox` and `NumericUpDown`).

This is how I am populating the controls currently:

```
 Form myForm = new Form();
 if (comboBoxTable.Text == "Client")
{
       myForm = new EditClientDataWindow();
 }
else if (comboBoxTable.Text == "Agency")
 {
       myForm = new EditAgencyDataWindow();
 }
else if (comboBoxTable.Text == "Medicine")
 {
       myForm = new EditMedicineDataWindow();
 }
string val;
foreach (Control c in myForm.Controls)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewMDB.ColumnCount; i++)
    {
          val = dataGridViewMDB.SelectedRows[0].Cells[i].Value.ToString();
          if (dataGridViewMDB.Columns[i].Name.ToString() ==
                            c.Name.ToLower().Replace(c.GetType().ToString().ToLower().Replace("system.windows.forms.", ""), ""))
          {
          if (c is NumericUpDown)
               (c as NumericUpDown).Value = Convert.ToInt32(val);
          else
               c.Text = val;
          }
    }
}
```

With the exception of `NumericUpDown`, the other types of controls are correctly populated.  For the `NumericUpDown`, I only ever get the default -1 value.  I've also tried to use `decimal.Parse()` and `Convert.ToDecimal()` instead of `Convert.ToInt32()`, but there is no change in the result.

The range of `NumericUpDown` had been set to -1 and 999.

Comment: _it seems not work_ is not a real question or problem report. Post the error messages / symptoms.

Comment: You code looks correctly, so most likely the reason is somewhere else. Maybe 12 as > or < Maximum or Minimum for numericUpDown1 or you assign it in a "wrong moment". May you show more code to make things clearer?

Comment: After the edit: still just "not work". What happens?

Comment: @wenLiangcan that 1 line of code you added completely changes the question and invalidates the only answer.  Are there any other lines of code you excluded that might be relevant?

Comment: You won't get an answer here, still too much unknowns. Use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer, but a way to reduce a space for error searching, because it's a lot of things going on under the hood.

Can you please change your code to

```
foreach (Control c in myForm.Controls)
{
    if (c is NumericUpDown)
       (c as NumericUpDown).Value = 12;
    else
       c.Text = "12";
}
```

After this all controls should be set to 12. Can you please test it and get back with the observations.

Comment: This kind of "Try it and report back" troubleshooting is not really appropriate for SO.  If you want to try to walk the OP through this problem, then chat is a better option.

Comment: thanks for your help,after testing by your advise,i found out the reason is that the condition i used can not match the NumericUpDown control with any of the column'name

Comment: @psubsee2003 and downvoters. Others, who try to help OP with his issue will not see our chat and obsticles which poped up there. Troubleshooting technics may be valueable not only for OP, but for others as well. Finaly, as it turned out my pseudo-answer helped wenLiangcan to solve his problem, so I don't see ANY reason not to answer the way I did. Read SO reglament carefully: "Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful".

Comment: @wenLiangcan Does this mean, you're question is solved?